# How can I extract table defintion from BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to duplicate specific table schema without the data.
Basically create a clean table with different name.

Say original table  `orders` as:

```
a integer
b string
c float
```

I want to create: `orders-copy` as:

```
a integer
b string
c float
```

BigQuery offers the `COPY` option from the UI but this also copy the data.
I wanted to manually create the table but it has 90+- columns.

I know that when creating a table there is an option `EDIT AS TEXT`, Is there a way to get the columns names and types in the same format from the existed table (`orders`) so the creation from the UI would be easy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you can do:

- As you mentioned you can use the `EDIT AS TEXT` option when creating a table. But manually adding column settings for large number of columns can be challenging
- You can use the BQ CLI.

  - There you can retrieve the schema of a table
  - You can then create an empty table from a schema
  - But this requires downloading and installing the CLI
- The BQ API should also have the same abilities as the CLI
- Or you can use the web view for a fast result

  - Copy the table as normal
  - Then write a query to delete from the copied table.

Here's such a query:

```
#standardSQL
DELETE FROM `BQ_project_name.dataset_name.table_name_COPY`
WHERE 1=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use API call to retrieve your table schema. Use this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get) to retrieve your table schema like this:

```
   {
    "name": "id",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "time",
    "type": "DATE",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "comment",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   }
```

and you could use it to create a table with schema by following this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_an_empty_table_with_a_schema_definition)